# Screen auto resize using Cordova for a mobile game (across different devices)

Tags: html, mobile, cordova

Is there a quick and easy function using Cordova API where a game's screen size is automatically resized based on the device detected, and the screen size detected?

Otherwise, I have to build my own library of devices that we can support, the OS we can support, etc. It will also limit the number of devices and markets we can support.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one: https://github.com/biodiv/cordova-screengod
You develop for a FULLHD device (1080x19xx), and `screengod` will adapt your design to all screens, across all devices with

```
screengod(['path/to/fullhd.css'],function(){
    /* do your stuff */
});
```

after deviceready.